# how to remove or hide video controls, not all, only fullscreen and volumn

Tags: html, video

I want to hide video controls, but still have paly&pause&progress, hide or remove volumn、fullscreen and the three dots icon in right-bottom

remove this icon:
[image]

i know attribut 'controls', but i don't want to hide all

Answer (score 1):

add this css code to your style-sheet:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button,
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: very thanks, i also want to hide right-bottom icon, this icon is three dot, it has download button and picture in picture button, how to hide this icon?

Comment: Hi @RtyXmd just add an attribute 

controlslist="nodownload noplaybackrate"